# Makefile cannot find .so files when running executable

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, .so

I am creating a C++ application with a Makefile in VScode and Ubuntu that uses the mosquitto MQTT protocol.

I cloned the [official repo](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto) under the `/usr/src/` directory and I am trying to link my makefile with the necessary shared object files using variables.

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

INCLUDES += -I/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp
INCLUDES += -I/usr/src/mosquitto/include

LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp -l:libmosquittopp.so.1
LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib -l:libmosquitto.so.1

BIN = bin

all: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BIN)/main $< $(LIBS)
run: 
    @./bin/*
clean:`
    rm -rf ./bin/*
```

The project structure consists of a single directory with a makefile and a `main.cpp` file, in addition to a `bin` folder to store the executable.

```bash
├── bin
├── main.cpp
├── makefile
```

So far, `main.cpp`'s only external dependency is on the `mosquittopp` header file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mosquittopp.h>

int main() {

    int mid_val {235};
    int* mid = &mid_val;

    const char* device_name {"mqtt_c8y_1234abc"};
    const char* username {[username]};
    const char* password {[password]};
    const char* host {"[domain].cumulocity.com"};
    const int port {1883};

    mosqpp::lib_init();

    mosqpp::mosquittopp mosq_client {device_name, true};

    int auth_status { mosq_client.username_pw_set(username, password)};

    if(auth_status == MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "User authentication success!\n"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to run the `build` target without a problem, but when I try to execute the `run` target I get the following error:

```bash
./bin/main: error while loading shared libraries: libmosquittopp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [makefile:15: run] Error 127
```

This occurs even though I can verify the correct location of the libraries and their names in my file system [**emphasis** added]:

```bash
/usr/src/mosquitto/lib$ tree
.
.
.

├── connect.c
├── connect.o
├── cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── **libmosquittopp.so.1**
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── mosquittopp.cpp
│   ├── mosquittopp.h
│   └── mosquittopp.o
├── dummypthread.h
├── handle_auth.c
.
.
.
├── helpers.c
├── helpers.o
├── **libmosquitto.so.1**
├── linker.version
```

**Please note**: I have already tried giving the shorthand name of the library files by listing them as `-lmosquittopp` and `-lmosquitto`, but then the makefile could not locate them when trying to run `all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I followed the advice posted on the reply to my question, but this time I set the names of the actual shared library files to their full name using the prefix colon `:` and the suffix `.so.1`, and it worked!

Here is the full code for the `LIBS` variable:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp -l:libmosquittopp.so.1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib -l:libmosquitto.so.1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/mosquitto/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamic libraries linking is done in two steps:

First the static linking done at build-time. For libraries installed in non-standard location you use the `-L` option to tell the linker where the libraries are located, as in `-L/path/to/library/directory`.

Then there's the runtime linking, done by the operating system when it loads and runs your program. It also needs to know the location for the libraries, and if they are not in a standard location they will not be found and you will get an error when attempting to run the application. When using the `g++` driver program you need to add the option `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/library/directory`.

Please note that these options are passed the *directory* where the libraries are located, and not the libraries themselves.

The error you get is from the second OS-level linking.

---

On another note, when linking with libraries that are in a standard location, or whose directory is added with `-L`, you don't need to supply the full filename, only the library name without the `lib` prefix or the `.so` suffix.

So instead of linking with `libmosquitto.so.1`, link with `mosquitto`.

Putting it all together, change your `LIBS` variables as this:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp -lmosquittopp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/mosquitto/lib/cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/src/mosquitto/lib -lmosquitto -Wl,-rpath,/usr/src/mosquitto/lib
```

Comment: Hello,

When I replaced my code with your code snippet and I am now getting the same error as before when I tried to link without the full file name:
```bash
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquittopp: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Other possibilities for supporting runtime linking: (i) add the library install directory to the dynamic linker's standard search path, which may be as easy as dropping a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`; (ii) use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable at runtime to dynamically add the installation directory to the dynamic linker's search path.  Either of these is better able to deal with changing the library's installation location, to the extent that that matters.